# Live check list elements amount and add some style for them with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list

i have some list, sometimes this lis have 5, sometimes have 7 elements. I want to check how many, and add for less than 5 some style. Si i have this, but it's not working... Maybe i need to add some live checking? Also i'v set time interval for some kind of late chacking. Thx, for help.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var single_producer_products_list = $('.single_producer_products_list').find('li');
    if ((single_producer_products_list < 7)) {
        $('.producer_series_info').addClass('longer');
    }
},200)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `length` property:

> The number of elements in the jQuery object.

```
$('.single_producer_products_list').find('li').length
```

Comment: i'v try this but it's not wotking :(

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski What you want is length property, if your code doesn't work the problem should be something else.

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski - what undefined is saying, is that if the `length` property doesn't work, the problem lies elsewhere in your code. `length` is a definite for this.

Comment: ok, i know what is wrong, i have two lists, and no specify where i need to checking this, but how can i do it?

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski Sorry, I don't get your question, if you have 2 lists and you want to select them separately you can use `eq` method. `$('.single_producer_products_list').eq(0).find('li').length` it selects the firm element with class of `single_producer_products_list`

Comment: ok, when i gave eq(0) nothing happens, but when i'v set eq(2) it's fine, what can be wrong?

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski `eq(2)` selects the third element, if you want to select the third element, everything is fine.

Comment: no, i need to check whole lists on this site, now i have three

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski So don't use `eq` method.

Comment: maybe i need to use each()? now function can't set class for my element becouse it dosn't know which element is depend on which list..

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
jQuery('.single_producer_products_list').children().length;
```